# Происхождение слова "кутья"

Tags: этимология

Продолжим рождественскую тему.
Тут обсуждалось слово "сочельник" - это слово, как следует из ответа, происходит от слова "сочево", то есть, блюдо из вареной пшеницы с медом. Но, насколько я знаю, это блюдо называется кутья.
А что это за слово? Оно явно старославянское, но хотелось бы узнать его происхождение.

Answer (score 1):

Нет, во-первых все-таки **сочиво** (другое написание почти не встречается, да и необъяснимо), а во-вторых, сочиво - это "сок" (масло) из семян и орехов - блюдо, приготовленное с использованием такого сока. Вот без такого "масляного сока" блюдо может быть кутьей, но не сочивом.

В христианской традиции сочиво по всем правилам приготовлять было не обязательно (хотя и желательно на рождество), поэтому блюдо это совершенно верно называли *кутьей*.

Кутья - слово греческое, означает "смесь" - в нашем случае зерен пшеницы или ячменя с орехами.

Подробнее - см. википедию. 
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8F

Answer (score 0):

По Фасмеру, заимствовано из новогреч. ("бобы") от греч. коккос -  зерно.